# How to Add Authorization in method Get Request swift

Tags: ios, swift, get

i need to add my authorization to get API in method Get.

i'v already code Authorization like this :

```
let oauth_consumer_key = "******"
    let oauth_consumer_secret = "*****"
    let oauth_token = "*****"
    let oauth_token_secret = "*****"

    let url = URL(string: "http.myurl.com")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)

    let a = OAuthSwiftClient(consumerKey: oauth_consumer_key, consumerSecret: oauth_consumer_secret, oauthToken: oauth_token, oauthTokenSecret: oauth_token_secret, version: .oauth1)

    let credential = a.credential
    let parameters = [String: AnyObject]()
    let authorization = credential.authorizationHeader(method: .GET, url: url! as URL, parameters: parameters)
```

so, how to add **authorization** to method Get request?

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure what’s going on with your specific code but setting the Authorization header manually is not the right approach.  Rather, you should set up your session to handle authentication challenges via the -URLSession:task:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler: delegate callback.

Comment: let username = "user"
let password = "pass"
let loginString = String(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
let loginData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString()

// create the request
let url = URL(string: "http://www.example.com/")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
// make sure your class conforms to NSURLConnectionDelegate
let urlConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)

Comment: i wanna make method get sir